# VNP = VP versus complexity classes in Arithmetic Geometry

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cr.crypto-security, conditional-results, one-way-function

What is the implication of $VNP = VP$ to cryptography schemes such as Elliptic curve/Abelian Variety/Arithmetic Geometry based cryptography? Are there any papers or books that talk about sophisticated encryption techniques and the possible complexity classes they belong to?

There seems to be a negative implication for **RSA** if $VNP = VP$. On the other hand no **OWF** should exist if $VNP = VP$. However relatively nothing is known about frailty of candidate **OWF** from Arithmetic Geometry if $VNP = VP$. Will these be safe?

Comment: Why do you say that no OWF should exist if VP=VNP? I agree that if P=NP then no OWF should exist, but VP=VNP is quite a bit weaker than that, a priori...

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow $VNP=VP\implies P/poly=NP/poly\implies NP\subseteq P/Poly\implies$ no $\mathsf{PRG}$s exist $\implies$ no $\mathsf{OWF}$s exist (from problem $7.3$, theorem $7.11$ here http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/prgs.pdf)

Comment: @Arul: Indeed. Sorry, I was thinking by default of complexity-theoretic (rather than cryptographic) OWFs, which have only a uniform hardness (not nonuniform). In fact, your reasoning seems to answer the question: any candidate OWF cannot be a cryptographic OWF (that is, against nonuniform adversaries) if VP=VNP. Over finite fields this is literally true, and over fields of characteristic zero it is true under GRH.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow sorry I dont follow 'is there diff b/w crypto OWF and complexity theoretic OWF?' For GRH as required are you using burgeisser's work? I thought OWF are defined against P/poly adversaries as in included links or more strongly against BPP adversaries. What is a complexity theoretic OWF?

Comment: @Arul: Yes, I was referring to Burgisser for GRH. Crypto OWF is defined against P/poly (or *more weakly* against BPP), and usually, as far as I understand it, need not be 1-1. Complexity OWF is typically defined as a 1-1 function computable in poly-time whose inverse is not computable in poly time (so, it's 1-1 by definition, and is defined against a P adversary).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I am sorry *more weakly* is right also is there a reference for complexity owf?

Comment: @Arul: They are sometimes also called "worst-case OWF" (since crypto OWF are also typically defined by an average-case notion of hardness); they exist iff P neq UP. See the references on the [zoo entry for UP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up), as well as papers that cite those papers.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow sorry I am more confused now. one way function do not exist implies we could have natural proofs? does it mean vp=vnp implies we can have natural proofs? or is the complexity theoretic owf is the one to consider here in the context of natural proofs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33668/discussion-between-joshua-grochow-and-arul).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I updated chat